# Blazor Server - Slow load or unresponsive but still loading on browser (deployed to Windows Server 2016. IIS8)

Tags: blazor-server-side, iis-8

Good Day everyone

We are currently testing our first Blazor Server application that is deployed on our Staging Server (Windows Server 2016 with IIS 8), we have noticed that, when the application is accessed by multiple users and doing some testing process, the application becomes slow, or sometimes when accessing the site again, the browser still loads the application but without rendering the design, we check it using the dev tools in google chrome, and on the network tab, it says "pending" under the time column.

We tried to ping the application, and it returns without too much latency, I don't know if this application side or on the server or the network, we deploy the project similar to our ASP.NET Core MVC projects, we are all testing the applications on our homes, because of the global pandemic.

Is there a different setup for Blazor Server when deploying to IIS?

I hope someone can help us with this.

Thanks, everyone, and regards.

**Edit**

We found the suspect, It's the Visual Studio JIT Debugger, yes we install VS2019 on our Staging Server, it's weird that we haven't encounter this from our other web application, is it because the project is in Blazor Server? when we check the server the JIT is running, and then the app is working again, I think when the application encounters an error, this shows up on the server side, and when it reach 3 JIT on the process, it will not continue to load the application.

I search for this and the answers is to disable the JIT Debugger, either in VS or in the register, is disabling this is the best solution??

Thanks again everyone.

Comment: You can try the method in this link: [https://bobcares.com/blog/iis-website-slow-to-load](https://bobcares.com/blog/iis-website-slow-to-load).

Comment: I'm facing this exact same problem, my server does not have the JIT Debugger installed though. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @AlexGarcia sorry for late response, no, we still haven't fix this, I disabled the JIT debugger on Visual Studio 2019, that is installed on the server, but still it still show on the server side.